# How can I ensure my project ownership is secure in Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am a beginner to Firebase as I've had a project (web-app) built for me by a developer on Fiverr.

Said website is hosted on firebase and connected to a custom domain.

The ownership has been transferred to me and I now own the project and it's custom website domain.

If thereotically a developer I work with in future wanted to "take over" my site is there any other protections I can put in place?

I just dont know if what I've mentioned above is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near project overview, you have an icon ⚙ > Project settings > User and Permissions. There should be your email address with role as owner. If there is a programmer, you can just remove him. But remember, you might not find a second one willing to change something in this code. And if you do, it might cost more.

If you're afraid he might be hacked and someone will delete your project, speak with him and give him a viewer role and just change it when you need some changes on your app.

Comment: Thanks, I've given him the editor role only when he's making edits to help my website. Apart from that he has the viewer role. Guess there's nothing else to do and I can stop "worrying" so much about it.  Appreciated